# how to minimize repetitive code in jquery?

Tags: jquery, minimize

How can I minimize the following bindings in jquery:

```
    var profileIdDefault = "Profile ID";
    var organisationIdDefault = "Competitor ID";
    var FromDateDefault = "From Date";
    var ToDateDefault = "To Date";


    $("#startDate").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === FromDateDefault) {
            $(this).attr("value", "");
        }
    });
    $("#startDate").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val(FromDateDefault);
        }
    });

    $("#endDate").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === ToDateDefault) {
            $(this).attr("value", "");
        }
    });
    $("#endDate").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val(ToDateDefault);
        }
    });

    $("#profileID").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === profileIdDefault) {
            $(this).attr("value", "");
        }
    });
    $("#profileID").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val(profileIdDefault);
        }
    });

    $("#organisationID").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === organisationIdDefault) {
            $(this).attr("value", "");
        }
    });
    $("#organisationID").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val(organisationIdDefault);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's your HTML markup look like?

Comment: Should be posted on Code Review instead

Comment: And, what you're really asking is "How to refactor this jquery code?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay DRY. Example:

```
function setup(id, toCompare) {
    $(id).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === toCompare) {
            $(this).attr("value", "");
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val(toCompare);
        }
    });
}
setup("#startDate", FromDateDefault);
setup("#endDate", ToDateDefault);
setup("#profileID", profileIdDefault);
setup("#organisationID", organisationIdDefault);
```

Comment: You are making 2 DOM operations by $(id). You can either cache the $(id) variable or take advantage of chainable property of jquery. It will save you 1 DOM operation. Just to make code more better..Anyways nice approach So +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this simply, by using the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

```
<input id="startdate" placeholder="From Date" /><br />
<input id="endDate" placeholder="To Date" /><br />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4D63b/)

Comment: I will do it using placeholder too..

Comment: That's of course the best solution. But HTML5 wasn't mentioned anywhere, as well as the question was not about alternative propositions, but about code refactoring to exclude repetitiveness.

Comment: As they say, "[The Best Code is No Code At All](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all.html)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
function toggleValue(valToCompare) {
     if ($(this).val() === valToCompare) {
         $(this).attr("value", "");
     } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
         $(this).val(valToCompare);
     }
}

$("#startDate").focus(function() {
    this.toggleValue(FromDateDefault);
}).blur(function() {
    this.toggleValue(FromDateDefault);
});
```

You can do the same for rest of the elements.

Comment: Not going to work, as `FromDateDefault` is not the only variable in use. You'd better include an additional parameter to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store some of the data in the element using a data attribute. Then you can test the value associated with the element. For example...

```
<input id="startdate" class="focus-value" data-empty="From Date" />
<input id="enddate" class="focus-value" data-empty="To Date" />
```

The in the jquery...

```
$(".focus-value").focus(function() { 
    if $(this).val() === $(this).data('empty') { 
         $(this).attr("value", "");
    }
});
```

Allowing you to combine all the focus and blur handlers.